# hibernate nativesqlquery batch insert

Tags: java, hibernate, batch-file

For reasons, not needed to divulge, I need to run a series of native SQL statements using the hibernate layer. They are the same statement (same bind variables) of the form "insert abc(column1,column2) values(:column1List, :column2List)".

I would like to execute this as a batch insert if possible. Can it be done ? If so how ?

I tried 

`sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
sqlQuery.setParameterList(.....)`

I think I found out the reason but I am not sure what's happening. The insert statement has more than 2 columns and hibernate is changing it into insert into abc(column1, column2, column3, column4,column5, column6) values ( ?,?, (?,?),(?,?),(?,?),?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on hibernate 4.1.4. I tried every trick I can think of to make it work. Hence I am on hibernate 4. I had to resort to implementing a class that did work "org.hibernate.jdbc.Work". Once I have a statement handle, everything went smooth and I got my answer. The approach is correct outlined by DaveB.

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction() ;
  SqlWork sqlWork = new SQLWork(a,b,c) ; // used inside execute <br/>
  session.doWork(sqlWork) ;
  tx.commit();
} catch (HibernateException he) {
tx.rollback();
} finally {
session.close()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to look at using JDBC for batch inserts, this will strip out the overheads associated with hibernate and allows you to work off a list of predefined parameters

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

//...

String sql = "insert into employee (name, city, phone) values (?, ?, ?)";
org.hibernate.Session sess = (org.hibernate.Session) em.getDelegate();
Connection conn = sess.connection();
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

for (Employee employee: employees) {

    ps.setString(1, employee.getName());
    ps.setString(2, employee.getCity());
    ps.setString(3, employee.getPhone());
    ps.addBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
ps.close();
connection.close();
```

Example taken from (http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/)

Comment: The system I am using does not give me a connection from session object like in your example. I am getting the session from hibernatesessionfactory. Do you know how I can get the connection ? Or do I have to get entityManager ? If so, how do I get the entityManager ? Thanks... Not too knowledgable about hibernate.. I am on hibernate 4.1.4

Comment: Hi @EnderWiggin yes the EntityManager bit is probably not relevant in your case, but once you have got hold of the Hibernate session the rest should be the same